# discretization of porous media equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system

I am trying to discretize the equation $u_t = \Delta (u^2)$ without using finite elements. If I use a Crank-Nicolson scheme I end up: 
$$\frac{u^{n+1}_j - u^n_j}{\Delta t} = \frac{(u^2)^{n+1}_{j+1} - 2(u^2)^{n+1}_j+(u^2)^{n+1}_{j-1}}{2(\Delta x)^2} + \frac{(u^2)^{n}_{j+1} - 2(u^2)^{n}_j+(u^2)^{n}_{j-1}}{2(\Delta x)^2} $$

Which then leads to $$u^{n+1}_j - \lambda ((u^2)^{n+1}_{j+1} - 2(u^2)^{n+1}_j+(u^2)^{n+1}_{j-1}) = u^n_j + \lambda((u^2)^{n}_{j+1} - 2(u^2)^{n}_j+(u^2)^{n}_{j-1}) $$ where $\lambda = \frac{\Delta t}{2 (\Delta x)^2}$.

I have no idea how to deal with the $(u^2)^{n+1}$ terms in my MATLAB code. Would it be best to use finite elements or is there a way that I can use finite difference methods for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no $u^2$ it is just $u$ because it is second order central difference,

consult this reference

```
NUMERICAL METHODS FOR PARABOLIC EQUATIONS
```

by LONG CHEN